# test tornado GET with JSON in curl

Tags: curl, tornado

trying to check this tornado get handler

```
def get(self):
    query = self.get_arguments('query')
    query = str(query)
    self.log(query)
    self.write('done')
```

later it should handle some json so I tried

```
curl -X GET -H "application/json" -d '{"query: { "test": "test"}}' http://localhost:8081/
```

but the log just shows []
how to correctly do that ?

Answer (score 0):

found it myself. must have been blind

```
def get(self):
    body = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
    for k in body:
        print(str(k) + ':' + str(body[k]))
```

and the curl

```
curl -d '{"option": "value", "something": "anothervalue"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X  GET http://localhost/json
```